# Using Limits with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

This is the code I have right now:

```
 var url = 'https://*****.firebaseio.com/photos';
var promise = angularFire(url, $scope, 'photos', {});

promise.then(function() {

    //limit here.

});
```

What code can I insert to limit what is returned from the firebase to only those have a specified priority (let's say the priority is "new)?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just pass in an already limited query to angularFire, like so:

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://*****.firebaseio.com/photos");
var promise = angularFire(ref.startAt("new"), $scope, "photos", {});
```

Comment: I ended up figuring it out ~10 seconds after the post, but this was exactly how I did it. Thanks!