# How to limit the number of objects passed into $firebase object?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to set the `angularjs` app with firebase connector angularfire. 
In my database I have an endless list and I want to display only the last 100 items and any new coming item.

according documentation the function `$firebase()` takes the the `Firebase` reference as argument with whatever url it was set up with. It automatically loads the content wich can be assigned to `$scope`. However what happens if there is a very long list of data? is there any option to limit the number of items pulled from `firebase` the same way as you would do it with when pulling the data directly from Firebase reference with `.limit()` ? I didn't find anything in angularfire documentation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179532/using-limits-with-angularfire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use limit() optionally with startAt() and endAt():

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
var limited = $firebase(ref.limit(100)); // last 100 messages
or 
var limited = $firebase(ref.endAt().limit(100)); // last 100 messages
or 
var limited = $firebase(ref.startAt().limit(100)); // first 100 messages
```

you can even pass a position from where to startAt or endAt as an argument:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limit.html